# Self-Hosted Devops agent - Config launching error

Tags: macos, devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying deploy self-hosted agent on my mac os machine. I downloaded agent archive and unpacked it. All attempts to run `config.sh` failed with an error:

> config.sh: line 85: ./bin/Agent.Listener: No such file or directory

[image]

Have no idea where I did a mistake.

**UPD**
First time I got another error message, but only one time.

> agent.listener cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I had to configure `Security & Privacy`, but now it workes fine.

[image]

Comment: This created one permission loop after another for my case to enable devops agent. Hence I had to go with first answer to disable the gatekeeper completely and then enable it back once configuration was done.

Answer (score 11):

try running command
sudo spctl --master-disable

Comment: To enable back after actions are completed use

`sudo spctl --master-enable`

Check status with `spctl --status`